# How to automatically store all ipython outputs into variable like `Out15` rather than the list component `Out[15]`?

Tags: ipython

ipython auto-completion is great, but a lot of times I need to use previous output and the form `Out[15]` doesn't get auto-completion. I always have to repeatly do an assignment:

```
out15=Out[15]
```

Then use out15 for autocompletion. 
Can we make this mechanism automatic?
( I know I can use `_`, but it lacks readability and if I re-run sth, it becomes untraceable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to do that in IPython, and I don't see any good reason you would like to store thing in Out15 more than in a list.

A better question would have been, 'how can I get completion on dictionary and list element without using an intermediary variable'.

Like for me, `Out[15].<tab>` does trigger completion. I just set the completer greedy option (`IPCompleter.greedy`) to `True`, either in my profile, or using the `%config` magic.

Still this has side effect like :

- if a attribute is in fact a property, it might get computed, which you might not want (like Sql query...etc).
- It also work other `dict`s and `list`s , like pandas, also on function like `'mystring'.upper().decdoe().<tab>` will work ... etc

Anyway that not what you asked, so it will probably not help you.

Comment: Didn't know there is `IPCompleter.greedy` option. Though this is not what I asked, this is exactly the problem I want to solve:). The other reason I want `out15` instead of `Out[15]` is just for less typing, and not that important.